# THREE JS Removing BOX Geometry from Merged Geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a 100k+ boxes that are added to a merged geometry.  I need to remove some geometries occasionally from this merged geometry.  Can I loop over the position attributes in steps of 108 or 72 vertices per cube to pull out the positions of these boxes or does merge also merge vertices?

```
function blockCubeAlter(grid, blockModel) {

        function getGridElevation(n, e, grid) {
            var y_grid = Math.floor((grid.metaData.yMax - n) / grid.metaData.yStep) + 1;
            var x_grid = Math.floor((e - grid.metaData.xMin) / grid.metaData.xStep);

            var array_pos = Math.round(y_grid * (grid.metaData.nCol + 1) + x_grid);
            return isNaN(grid.elevations[array_pos]) ? Infinity : grid.elevations[array_pos];
        }

        var tmpBox = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(blockModel.x_step, blockModel.y_step, 2);

        var myBlock = scene.getObjectByName('blockModel');

        var pointsPerVertex = 3,
            vertexPerFace = 4,// this might be 3 triangles?
            facePerSide = 1, // this might be 2 triangles per face?
            sidePerBox = 6;

        var pointsPerCube = pointsPerVertex * vertexPerFace * facePerSide * sidePerBox;
        for (var i = 0, j = myBlock.geometry.attributes.position.array.length; i < j; i += pointsPerCube) {
            var above = false,
                below = false;

            for (var k = i; k < i + pointsPerCube; k += pointsPerVertex) {
                var n = myBlock.geometry.attributes.position.array[k + 1];
                var e = myBlock.geometry.attributes.position.array[k + 0];
                var z = myBlock.geometry.attributes.position.array[k + 2];
                if (z > getGridElevation(n + WEBGLyTranslate, e + WEBGLxTranslate, grid))
                    above = true;
                else
                    below = true;
                if (above && below) break; // intersect surface
            }
            if (above) {
                if (below) {
                    var newBoxGeometry = tmpBox.clone();
                    newBoxGeometry.attributes.position.array = myBlock.geometry.attributes.position.array.slice(i, i + pointsPerCube);
                    for (var materialGroupIndex = 0, z = myBlock.geometry.groups.length; materialGroupIndex < z; materialGroupIndex++) {
                        var myGeometryGroup = myBlock.geometry.groups[materialGroupIndex];
                        if (i >= myGeometryGroup.start && i < myGeometryGroup.start + myGeometryGroup.count) {
                            var newMaterial = myBlock.material.materials[myGeometryGroup.materialIndex].clone();
                            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(newBoxGeometry, newMaterial)
                            scene.add(mesh);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (var k = i; k < i + pointsPerCube; k++) {
                    myBlock.geometry.attributes.position.array[k] = undefined;
                }
            }
        }

        myBlock.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;

    }
```

I am getting pretty random results. how does merge set the position array, does it merge vertices or just append?

Answer (score 0):

As seen in my comments the number of vertex between the tmpBox and the vertices per box in the merged blockModel were not the same.  This change in vertices was because the orginal merge was made from boxGeometry, merged, and then converted to buffer geometry.  this was how the merged mesh was converted.

```
finalGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(tmpGeometry);
```

I was able to resolve the issue by creating the tmpBox by using:

```
var tmpBox = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(new THREE.BoxGeometry(blockModel.x_step, blockModel.y_step, 2));
```

seems odd that

```
new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(new THREE.BoxGeometry(blockModel.x_step, blockModel.y_step, 2)) != new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(blockModel.x_step, blockModel.y_step, 2);
```

But they have different number of vertices.  I think one is using a 4 vertexed face and the other is using three vertices faces.

Comment: The confusion of this ended up being because of indexed vs non-indexed geometries.  While optimizing code i found the boxBufferGeometry uses index vertices from the position array but once merged it uses "triangle soup" no indexed vertices.  Actually ending up removing merge all together and assigning the position array to a buffergeometry directly.